# Getting 2 result columns from SQL query

Tags: sql

I've tried to make an SQL query to get 2 result columns from 1 query. To elaborate:

This is my query:

```
SELECT Name, AVG(DATEDIFF(day,[Open Date],[Close Date])) 
FROM Inventory Where Tested ='Yes' AND [Close Date] IS NOT NULL AND [Open Date] IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY Name
```

My result:

[image]

My desired result:
When also `Where Tested = 'No'`

[image]

How to write an SQL query with `Where Tested = 'Yes'` and `Where Tested = 'No'`? Where Tested = 'Yes' is Column 1 result and Tested = 'No' is Column 2 result.

Database:SQL server 2019

Comment: Please share a [mre] of your database table, including schema and sample data. In addition, please specify what database provider you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EJC answer with subqueries should already probably help with what you need, but just wanted to share some other options to achieve this:

1. Joining two separate queries

```sql
SELECT tested.Name, tested.TestedAVG, not_tested.NotTestedAVG FROM

(SELECT Name, AVG(DATEDIFF(day,[Open Date],[Close Date])) as "TestedAVG"
FROM Inventory 
WHERE Tested ='Yes' AND [Close Date] IS NOT NULL AND [Open Date] IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY Name) tested

FULL JOIN

(SELECT Name, AVG(DATEDIFF(day,[Open Date],[Close Date])) as "NotTestedAVG"
FROM Inventory 
WHERE Tested ='No' AND [Close Date] IS NOT NULL AND [Open Date] IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY Name) not_tested

ON tested.Name = not_tested.Name
```

2. Using case

```sql
SELECT Name, 
AVG(CASE WHEN Tested ='Yes' THEN DATEDIFF(day,[Open Date],[Close Date]) END) as [Tested AVG],
AVG(CASE WHEN Tested ='No' THEN DATEDIFF(day,[Open Date],[Close Date]) END) as [Not Tested AVG]
FROM Inventory 
WHERE [Close Date] IS NOT NULL AND [Open Date] IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY Name
```

3. Adding as group by

If you don't need to have it as a separate column, the easiest way would be to add a group by the `Tested` column as well.

```sql
SELECT Name, AVG(DATEDIFF(day,[Open Date],[Close Date])) as "AVG"
FROM Inventory
WHERE [Close Date] IS NOT NULL AND [Open Date] IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY Name, Tested
```

Then you'll get this structure:

| Name | Tested | AVG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aTPO | Yes | 56 |
| aTPO | No | 50 |

Comment: Your option 2 is better than what I wrote and more along the lines of what I was thinking. It's been a while since I've done any sql.

Comment: Thank you. All of your answers work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say exactly what you want, but maybe you could use a couple of subqueries?

```
SELECT Name, 
AVG(select DATEDIFF(i2.day,i2.[Open Date],i2.[Close Date]) from inventory i2 where i2.name = i.name and i2.Tested = 'Yes') as "Tested", 
AVG(select DATEDIFF(i3.day,i3.[Open Date],i3.[Close Date]) from inventory i3 where i3.name = i.name and i3.Tested = 'No') as "Not Tested" 
FROM Inventory i
Where [Close Date] IS NOT NULL AND [Open Date] IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of three columns if you trying to get two columns with its values, you have to specify those columns in your code.
Example:

```sql
SELECT column1, column2 
FROM table_name
```

But if you want to find all the columns
Example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name
```